# CSS selection based on existence of sibling content

Tags: javascript, css

This as part of CSS selector learning I came across this problem. I am trying to select an element based on the existence of a sibling element. So If I have to quote an example,

```
<div class = "parentDiv">
  <div class = "abc">
    <span>Note</span>
  </div>
  <div class = "abd">
    <span><a>testLink</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class = "parentDiv">
  <div class = "abc">
    <span>Note2</span>
  </div>
  <div class = "abd">
    <span>te</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

For the above example, I am trying to select all span elements inside class `.abc` if its sibling `.abd` has an `a` tag

What I tried is `document.querySelectorAll('.parentDiv > .abc span ~ .abd span a');` which doesnt seem to work.. any idea what I could be doing wrong

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/p6nz011p/1/)

Comment: Please check updated fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/p6nz011p/2/

Comment: It would be great if you could accept an answer, if any, that solve your question, or let us know what is missing, so we can find one that does.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

It is an alternative using pure JavaScript:

```js
var selectors = document.querySelectorAll('.abd span a');

if (selectors) {
  selectors.forEach(function(selector) {
    selector.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    selector = selector.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    elements = selector.querySelectorAll('.abc span');
    if (elements) {
      elements.forEach(function(element) {
        element.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      });
      console.log('.abc span: ' + elements.length);
    }
  });

  console.log('.abd span a: ' + selectors.length);
}
```

```html
<div class="parentDiv">
  <div class="abc">
    <span>Class> abc, tag> span: 1.0</span><br>
    <div>Class> abc, tag> div: 1.0</div>
    <span>Class> abc, tag> span: 1.1</span><br>
    <span>Class> abc, tag> span: 1.2</span><br>
    <div>Class> abc, tag> div: 1.1</div>
    <div>Class> abc, tag> div: 1.2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="abd">
    <span><a>Class> abd, tag> span a : 1.0 </a></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parentDiv">
  <div class="abc">
    <span>Class> abc, tag> span: 2.0</span><br>
    <span>Class> abc, tag> span: 2.1</span><br>
    <span>Class> abc, tag> span: 1.2</span><br>
  </div>
  <div class="abd">
    <span>class> abd, tag> span: 2.0</span>
  </div>
  <div class="parentDiv">
    <div class="abc">
      <span>Class> abc: 3.0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="abd">
      <span><a>Class> abd, tag> span a : 3.0</a></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="parentDiv">
    <div class="abc">
      <span>Class> abc, tag> span: 4.0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="abd">
      <span>Class> abd, tag> span: 4.0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="abc">
      <span>Class> abc, tag> span: 4.1</span><br>
      <span>Class> abc, tag> span: 4.2</span><br>
      <span>Class> abc, tag> span: 4.3</span><br>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: this selects all the a tags and elements with .abc class not the spans

Comment: its still wrong the result should return one element  "first span" your example selects a tags and spans

Comment: That is not possible using ONLY css. I can do a JavaScript version if you want as an alternative.

Comment: Watch out: [NodeList.forEach() is not supported by Internet Explorer or Edge and is a very recent addition to both Firefox and Chrome](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: This is not a library to support all the browsers. This is just an alternative of how to solve the problem mentioned by the user, he didn't ask for "all browsers support" or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done with CSS selectors alone ([yet](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Ahas)).

The `~` selector selects elements on the same level in the DOM tree. Your `a` element isn't a direct sibling to your `span`, which is why your selector fails to return any results.

```
//What you'll want to do, is first select all instances of links:
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.parentDiv > .abd span a');

//Let's also create an empty array for matches:
var s = [];

//Then iterate over our matches:
Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, findSiblings);

function findSiblings(link){
    //Here, we can traverse back up to .parentDiv:
    var parent = link.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
    //Now, we have a only '.parentDiv's that contain '>.abd span a'. 
    //Let's run another query on that element to find any spans contained in '.abc':
    var spans = parent.querySelectorAll('.abc span');
    //Now, we have a new collection. Let's push each to our array:
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(spans, function(element){
        s.push(element)
    });
}

//Now, we have all the matches in our s-array:
alert(s.length);
```

Demo + a more compact version of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/p6nz011p/6/

---

Or, if you're using jQuery, you could simply do:

```
var s = $('.parentDiv:has(>.abd span a) >.abc span');
alert(s.length);
```

Note, that once browsers have support for the [CSS Selectors Level 4 `:has()` selector](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Ahas), you may use this selector without jQuery in `querySelectorAll()`, too.

Answer (score 0):

The tilde combinator selects only if the operands are childrens of the same parent. They must be at the same level. [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors).